# What happends when you convert floating point numbers to fixed point numbers in java (java me specifically)

Tags: java, java-me, floating-point, fixed-point, raycasting

I want my **java me** program to run as efficiently as possible. my goal is to make a ray cast and want to know the best way to traverse voxels. I have heard that conversion and comparison of floating point numbers is very CPU intensive. So I figured why not add a certain distance to each rays x and y, truncate the remainder, and use those coordinates to then check an octree for a voxel. Basically, is there a better way of going about doing something like this for a **java me** program?

Truncating floating point numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>"Floating point math is slow" is old wisdom - however, it is also outdated wisdom. On modern desktop CPUs, floating point computations are fast, and there is little to gain on fixed-point computations.</strike>

Edit after having reread the question title: The approach you describe is perfectly viable, except that you need to multiply, not add to, each number. However, you should first write a small performance test program that checks whether the kind of computations you intend to do will actually benefit from fixed-point math on the hardware where you intend to run your program.

Comment: crap I mentioned it in the title but forgot to say in the body that this is for a java me project

Comment: @Aasmund Eldhuset: you mention *"modern desktop CPUs"* but the OP specifically mentionned **Java ME**.  Somehow I don't think there are that many Java ME VMs on modern *desktop* CPUs ; )   When I was working in the mobile industry there was still a **lot** to gain by using fixed-point computation but it was a few years and I know things are moving fast.  I don't know if it's still useful or not since I don't work on mobile apps anymore : (

Comment: D'oh - sloppy reading on my part. Then, it might be a good idea - see my edited post.

Comment: Why multiply and not add? is multiplication cheaper on the cpu?

Comment: @user713635: Depends on the kind of computations you want to do (I haven't done much graphics, so I don't know how raycasting works) - multiplication preserves ratios and destroys differences, while addition preserves differences and destroys ratios. I'm quite sure that you should multiply and truncate if you want to convert to fixed-point; addition followed by truncation would cause all numbers that are less than 1 to become equal.

Comment: oh duh! Addition wouldn't work with negative numbers right? Thanks for your input. I'm pretty new to programming so your help is greatly appreciated!